# Jquery validation with multi field

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a form with three select box and one hidden field. I want to validate a string that is created from three select box's value is included in hidden field.

Exampe.

```
<form>
    <select name="s1">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <select name="s2">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <select name="s3">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">1</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="result" value="#123#245#" />
</form>
```

I want to valid join(s1.val, s2.val, s3.val) in result.val by jquery validation.

How can I do? I know that I need create custom rule.

Please help me.

Comment: Means you want to concatenate value of select and then compare with hidden field?

Comment: Add closing tag for option.

Comment: @KrupeshKotecha: Yes, that's want I want.

Comment: ohk cool. have you tried anything by yourself?

Comment: Yes, now I try to implement it by add custom's rule for jquery-validation and apple this rule to hidden field.

Comment: after you join s1.val, s2.val, s3.val your result could be #212# or #121# or #111# and anything else....  but the value of hidden field is "#123#245#". so let me know if value of hidden field can also be only 3 digits starting and ending with "#"

Answer (score 0):

As mention above in the comment

html code:

```
<form>
    <select name="s1">
         <option value="1">
         <option selected value="2">
    </select>

    <select name="s2">
        <option selected value="1">
        <option value="2">
    </select>

    <select name="s3">
    <option value="1">
    <option selected value="2">
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" name="result" id="hiddenVal" value="#212#" />
</form>
```

javaScript or jquery  code:

```
var str = "#";
$('form select').each(function(){
   str = str + $(this).val();
});

str +="#";
alert(str);
if($("#hiddenVal").val() == str){
   alert("yes value from select and value from hidden field is equal");
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dinker/f7s543dr/)

Comment: Not correct that I need, I must use jquery validation plugin to validate it.

Answer (score -1):

```
var concate_string = "";
$('form select').each(function(){
concate_string = concate_string +"#"+$(this).val();
});

concate_string = concate_string +"#";
if($('[name="result"]:eq(0)')==concate_string){
//your action ?
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know that way but I want to use jquery-validation.

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.